# SQL - Converting MONTH extract from number to full month name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having trouble with a particular stored procedure. I think I have it mostly correct...
I basically want to be able to search for a month and year and have any products' rows sold within that timeline show up.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_products
    @productname    CHAR(20),
    @month      CHAR(9),
    @year           CHAR(4)


AS
SELECT  p.ProductName, 
        p.UnitPrice, 
        p.UnitsInStock,
        s.Name

FROM        Orders o
INNER JOIN  OrderDetails od
ON          o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN  Products p
ON          od.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN  Suppliers s
ON          p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID 

WHERE   p.ProductName = @productname
AND     MONTH(o.OrderDate) = @month
AND     YEAR(o.OrderDate) = @year
```

Giving me a "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'December ' to data type int." error.

Here's the query it needs to work with:

```
EXEC sp_products '%tofu%', 'December', 1992
```

I think I know what I need to do, just don't know how to do it...
Help!

Comment: Are you converting from int to varchar at all? What is the datatype of the MONTH in your table?

Answer (score 1):

MONTH() returns an int.

Instead of MONTH(o.OrderDate), try DATENAME(m, o.OrderDate)

EDIT:

Also note that your input will not give you results are you are using wildcards without using the LIKE operator.

Update your procedure with this line:

```
WHERE p.ProductName LIKE @productname
```

Comment: Well no errors, but didn't return anything... I think you're on to something though!  Thanks!

Comment: you are using wildcards in your product name, but you are using "=" for comparison. To get results with your input of "%tofu%', change p.ProductName = /@ProductName to p.ProductName LIKE /@ProductName

Comment: LOL, it seems that mutilpe @ signs are not appreciated by stackoverflow. Remove the forward slashes in the example above

Answer (score 1):

The following two conditions are probably making your query non-[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), because in each case you are applying a function to a column being filtered on:

```
AND     MONTH(o.OrderDate) = @month
AND     YEAR(o.OrderDate) = @year
```

I would change them like this:

```
SELECT     …
           …
           …

FROM       Orders o

/* this join actually replaces those two filters */
INNER JOIN (SELECT CAST('1-' + @month + CAST(-@year AS varchar(5))) AS Month) d
ON         o.OrderDate >= d.Month AND o.OrderDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.Month)

INNER JOIN … /* the rest of your joins */

WHERE      p.ProductName = @productname  /* only one condition here now */
```

That is, the `@year` and `@month` arguments are formatted as a string convertible to a datetime value representing the first of the corresponding month, then you are besically filtering using this logic:

```
order date >= the first of the given month
and
order date < the first of the next month after the given
```

And of course, as you've already been told, the `@productname` filter in your query should probably use the `LIKE` comparison instead of the `=`, because it seems like you want to search by a mask as well as by a specific name. So the `WHERE` clause would then look like this:

```
WHERE      p.ProductName LIKE @productname
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a month string to a 1-12 representation of a month, use the inbuilt function `DATENAME` - reconstruct your date with something like, 01 December 1922, then use that for the input into `DATENAME`

Comment: Ok, thanks, but let's say I can't change the input... what would I do then?

Comment: You have to do some post-processing of the input. Reconstruct a datetime with the day = 1 (it's irrevalant), and the month/year of your input.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by jlnorsworthy

"Instead of MONTH(o.OrderDate), try DATENAME(m, o.OrderDate)"

This will work

For no result pls check what the input you are passing

EXEC sp_products **'%tofu%'**, 'December', 1992

you are comparing it with = operator

```
WHERE   p.ProductName = @productname
```

change = to like it will work.